# JTable properties change at runtime

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

How can I change the particular cell properties at run time in JTable.if the particular cell is name means  I need to change Font Size,Font Style ,etc.

If I click particular cell for EDIT I need to change that text's Font size, Font style etc.

How to do this

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)'s view, then you have to implement a [renderer/editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender); you can check the value of `isSelected()`. Also convenient is overriding [`prepareRenderer()`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:714968%20prepareRenderer).